# ORDER BY AND CASE IN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case

I need to have an order by functionality inside a stored procedure. A value is posted to a webservice and based on that value I have to order the results in a certain way i.e.

When ColName is posted order by ColName
When ColName2 is posted order by ColName2

I was looking into using Case but I am getting an error:

```
  Incorrect syntax near '@version' 
  ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN @OrderBy ='Seller (code)' THEN A_SNO 
  WHEN @OrderBy ='Lot' THEN A_LOTNO 
  WHEN @OrderBy ='Ring Type' THEN RN_NUM 
  WHEN @OrderBy ='Aim Error Code' THEN AimRejectionCode 
  ELSE A_SNO END

  DECLARE @version varchar(50)
  SET @version = (SELECT DBVERSION FROM MSYSCFG)
  PRINT 'New Version = ' + @version
```

Sorry I'm new to this and using sql server 2008. Any help appreciated
UPDATE: Provided additional code. When I leave out the last 3 lines I get an error of

```
 Incorrect synatx near END
```

UPDATE2: I've changed the ORDER BY TO the following:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN @OrderBy = 'Seller (code)' THEN A_SNO
        WHEN @OrderBy = 'Lot' THEN A_LOTNO
        WHEN @OrderBy = 'Aim Error Code' THEN AimRejectionCode
    END
    , CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'Ring Type' THEN RingTypeFlag
    END
    , A_SNO
```

The first three are varchar and the other is of type int.
This is giving me red lines under all three '=' with an error description of: 
`'incorrect syntax near '='` 
and a red line under ORDER BY which gives an error description of:

```
'A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 3'
```

Note when I remove the final `, A_SNO` The Order By error is gone but I am still receiving the = syntax error

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Col1' THEN Col1 ....likewise for all Cols....ELSE Col1 
END

Comment: @Vinayak I've made the change but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Okay, so what actually comes after the code you've shown? If removing the last three lines causes the same error to be reported but at a different location then it tends to indicate that the error is in what's actually following the block you've shown - or if that's the actual end of your code, then I'd suggest it's one or more absent `END`s for some `BEGIN`s at the start of your script.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I reverted to an earlier version of the sp and changed the order by and it worked. I must have deleted something unknowingly, though I still can't see whats different between the two. It runs now but I when I varchars I am receiving the following error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '31C' to data type int.'

Comment: Okay, great. *now* you need the solution I posted about where you shouldn't have `int` columns and `varchar` columns both trying to supply values for a *single* `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever okay thanks. So am I right in thinking that two columns with the same type are compatible?

Comment: Yes, in my example I assumed that `Col1` and `Col3` were compatible (e.g. one is `varchar(20)` and the other is `varchar(50)`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is an *expression* and has to produce a result of a single well defined type. So as long as the types of all columns are compatible, they can all be placed into a single `CASE` expression.

If that's *not* the case then you need to split it up and use *multiple* expressions. Say that `Col1` and `Col3` have compatible types (whether the same or you're happy for one to convert to the other) and that `Col2` and `Col4` have incompatible types (both between themselves and with `Col1` and `Col3`), then we need *three* expressions:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN 'Col1' THEN Col1
        WHEN 'Col3' THEN Col3
    END
    , CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'Col2' THEN Col2 END
    , CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'Col4' THEN Col4 END
    , Col1
```

(I've also include a final expression of `Col1` so that your "fallback" sort still occurs)

For each of the `CASE` expressions above, if no match occurs then the expression returns `NULL` - and all `NULL`s sort together, so that that entire `CASE` expression then has no overall effect on the sorting.

---

From [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> ### Return Types
>
> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in *result_expressions* and the optional *else_result_expression*.

Comment: thanks, I can also use case XYZ when 'A' then 1 else 2 end asc/desc !

Answer (score 0):

Let see if this is what you need:

```
DECLARE @t table(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int,col4 int);
DECLARE @OrderBy varchar(4) = 'Col3';

insert into @t 
values
 (1,2,3,4),
 (6,3,8,5),
 (7,4,1,7),
 (3,7,0,1),
 (9,8,3,6);

 SELECT 
     CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN 'Col2' THEN Col2
        WHEN 'Col3' THEN Col3
        WHEN 'Col4' THEN Col4
        ELSE Col1 END as OrderCol
    ,* 
 FROM @t
 ORDER BY OrderCol desc;

 SELECT * 
 from @t
 ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy
    WHEN 'Col2' THEN Col2
    WHEN 'Col3' THEN Col3
    WHEN 'Col4' THEN Col4
    ELSE Col1 END desc;
```