# C# Trying to write a simple Order by:Case for Ms Access, and having problems

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sql-order-by, case

I'm receiving a "Missing Operator" error when I execute my command.

What i'm trying to do is order my table by the rows, specifying priority to certain row values versus others using a case. This is my first time using it, going off of other examples, this should be working... unless MS Access is incapable of this.

Here's my simplified code for testing:

```
Select * From ACTable ORDER BY CASE WHEN Accounts = 'Revenues' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END Accounts
```

It's the same way written in the command text, one thing i was wondering is whether i should have switched out the single quotes for doubles.

It would have up to five 'when's to specify priority of the column values to appear at the top of the table. However, I can't seem to get it to work. Perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way.

When I get it working, I intend to plug it into this block:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Amount_USD) SELECT * FROM ACTable GROUP BY Accounts ORDER BY Accounts + MyCase + PIVOT Regime;
```

So my intended output is a pivoted table with the left most column containing Accounts, 7 in total, of which five must be in perfect order 1,2,3,4,5 and the remaining are appended, the top column containing regions, and the range of cells containing money values.

Now, I don't need help with the transform query since I already got it working, just posted it to give an idea of what I intend to do with it. OLEDB doesnt seem to recognize the keyword WHEN when I run this, other times, I receive a Missing operator error. Any ideas?

EDIT: So that was actually an IIF, which seems to be an access/vba specific thing, not sure if I should use it. Here's another thread I found citing the same use: [Order rows according to which condition is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093814/order-rows-according-to-which-condition-is-met?rq=1)

Comment: Did you check [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096572/order-by-and-case-in-sql-server)? Duplicate?

Comment: Also please post your `CREATE TABLE` description, or an equivalent thereof. Did you try `WHEN column = ...` instead of `accounts( column )` ?

Comment: Did you try `CASE column WHEN 'Revenues' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`?

Comment: @flutter Yes, I looked around and found examples pertaining to mysql and sql server, and I followed the code examples and I'm receiving the above error. What I want to know is if this is one of those MSAccess specific things. Maybe things are different for ms access, as I've experienced many times in the past. I'll fix my code.

Comment: @flutter, For example, I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695916/ms-access-vba-order-by-case-when that seems to suggest I have to use IF instead of When. Didn't see this earlier, though it is for VBA. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# How do I Order By my Transform/Pivot in Ms Access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018043/c-sharp-how-do-i-order-by-my-transform-pivot-in-ms-access)