# C# How do I Order By my Transform/Pivot in Ms Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, pivot

Using this code:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Amount) SELECT DISTINCT IS_Accounts FROM [TABLE] GROUP BY IS_Accounts PIVOT Status
```

I am capable of creating a mini-report summary for my purposes, generated from a much larger database with only the important stuff.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

However the Accounts column is all out of order, some of these need to be above the others in priority. To do this, I've written a query and tested it on the main database.

```
" ORDER BY IIf([IS_Accounts] = 'Revenues' , 1 , IIf([IS_Accounts] = 'Cost of Services', 2 , IIf([IS_Accounts] = 'Operating Expenses', 3, IIf([IS_Accounts] = 'Other income/expense', 4, IIf([IS_Accounts] = 'Income Taxes', 5, 6))))) ASC ");
```

When I run this on my main database, it properly gets sorted with revenues at the top and the rest as the pattern suggests, however plugging this to my Transform/Pivot query, I encounter a "Group by clause conflicts with Order by clause" error. If this operation is not allowed, how can I order my pivot data?

Note that I used IIF instead of a case, this is because MS Access cannot use when unlike other databases.

All I intend to do is make it so that the final rows of my pivot follow the correct pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a field in query called [Sort] (or whatever you want) with expression:

`Switch([IS_Accounts] = 'Revenues',  1, [IS_Accounts] = 'Cost of Services', 2, [IS_Accounts] = 'Operating Expenses', 3, [IS_Accounts] = 'Other income/expense', 4, [IS_Accounts] = 'Income Taxes', 5, True, 6)`

Now assign that field as another RowHeading in the CROSSTAB.

I presume you already have a lookup table of these budget items used as source for entry into data records. This sequence number could be another field in that lookup table. Join the table into the CROSSTAB to pull in the sequence number. Are you saving the actual descriptive text into your data records instead of a PK from the lookup table? Repeating this text will use up Access 2GB limit faster but that could still take a very long time depending on your data volume. Also, joins are supposed to perform more efficiently when done on numeric data.

Comment: Ok, that's alot of information for someone new to access. Having worked on other DB's, I assumed something's would be different, the 2GB limit is a surprise. Rather small. I suppose you mean I can fix this by splitting the tables up to different files? I come from a primarily C# background and have not used the SQL aspects of access, but instead interface to it through SQL commands and such. Because of this, I was wondering if you could clarify what you meant about: a Lookup table. I'm familliar with the Excel variant though; The Desc text to PK, what do you mean?

Comment: So, the gist you mean is to create that working order by select, and join it to the main table (view) as is and remove the actual select of the column from my original pivot? That could work I suppose. The 2GB limit is alarming though, is there any way past linking tables? These can reach as much as 270000 + rows of data. (Though in excel, that's a measely 10 mb, bad for scaling though)

Comment: PK = primary key. Sounds like you need to study a primer on relational database concepts. Google 'lookup table'.

Comment: Ah, right, I knew about those but they are called differently in my language.